# Как сохранить переменную,чтобы при следующем вводе появилась новая и осталась прежняя

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Мне нужно, чтобы админ вводил определенную переменную через `message.text` и она оставалась в словаре, но когда админ вводит эту же переменную еще раз, она просто заменяется в словаре.

Как сделать так, чтобы после использования переменной один раз в следующий раз ее название изменялось

```
def chekii2(message):
    global balans
    balans = message.text
    chekiiii[kkkk] = balans
    bot.delete_message(message.chat.id, message.message_id)
    bot.send_message(admin_id, 'Баланс изменен ')
```

то есть мне нужно изменять баланс для определенного пользователя, с начало админ вводит айди пользователя, которому хочет изменить баланс, потом вводит значение баланса, они сохраняются в списке и айди пользователя проверяется через список и если там есть его айди, то выводится его баланс:

```
    if message.from_user.id in chekiiii.keys():
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id,chekiiii[kkkk])
```

Comment: Что должно храниться в ключах словаря, а что в их значениях?

Comment: в ключе-айди,в значении-баланс пользователя